# Is it possible to actually stop your premium subscription instead of just stopping renewal?

Tags: roblox

I am going to upgrade to a higher tier of Premium, but I have to wait until my subscription expires. Do I have to wait until it expires, or is it possible to actually stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [forums](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/roblox-premium-is-here/355721/172) and the [help](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203312750-Upgrade-or-Downgrade-Membership) pages, it looks like the answer to your question is yes, you will have to wait until it actually expiries before upgrading. The information looks consistent across the site as well, as [this](https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024256251-Premium-Membership) help page states the same info.

Forum: [image: Roblox Forum]

Help - Upgrade or Downgrade Membership: [image: Roblox Help]

Help - Premium Membership: [image: Roblox Help]

I suggest cancelling it now as to avoid the hassle of forgetting and having to wait another month.